# When to run magento:setup:compile?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, development, compiler, setup-di-compile

If this question has been answered elsewhere I will delete this one. From a good look around, there doesn't seem to be a solid answer.

When I am developing an extension for Magento 2(.1), do I have to run `php magento setup:di:compile` every time a change is made to the `di.xml`?

Also, when is the appropriate time to run this command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Yes you will need to run **bin/magento setup:di:compile** everytime
>   when you added new classes with dependencies (constructor parameters)
>   or changed dependencies of existing classes.(di.xml)

Another main thing here is **Code compilation**. **setup:di:compile command** compiles your code everytime. its compile the code and check is there any error in that code or not , if error is there it will show directly on the command prompt in red color.

> While developing your extension in magento 2 and upper versions 
>   whenever you change any custom logic or some front end side operations
>   there is no need to run this command . But if you change something in
>   either `di.xml` or `class` ,`factory method` etc etc ... then you must
>   need to run this command.

**Refer this link for more details -** http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler.html